# org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: null value in column "category_id" violates not-null constraint

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, jpa, parent-child

i have a weird issue : i'am trying to save a User in my DB, this user has a list of skills. those skills are already in the db with linked categories and categories have linked domains. the structure looks like this : [image]

when i print the list of skills from the applicant i have this :

```
skills=[Skill{categories=[Category{domains=[Domain{id=4, name=DevOps}], id=13, name=BackEnd}], id=23, name=Java}, Skill{categories=[Category{domains=[Domain{id=4, name=DevOps}], id=13, name=BackEnd}], id=24, name=C}],
```

and here is the table making the link between Applicant and skills :

[image]

but when i'm trying to save the applicant i have this  Détail : Failing row contains (23, null, null, 499). can someone explain me ? I'm working on a spring application using jpa annotaions.

EDIT 1 :

ApplicantEntity :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ATS_APPLICANT")
public class ApplicantEntity implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "home", unique = false, nullable = true)
    private Boolean home;

    @Column(name = "anonymous", unique = false, nullable = true)
    private Boolean anonymous;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "job_type")
    private JobType jobType;

    @Column(name = "min_salary", unique = false, nullable = true)
    private Integer minSalary;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(unique = true)
    private UserEntity user;

    @OneToMany(targetEntity = ApplicantWorkExperienceEntity.class, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<ApplicantWorkExperienceEntity> applicantWorkExperiences = new ArrayList<ApplicantWorkExperienceEntity>();

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
    @JoinTable(name = "ATS_APPLICANT_SKILL", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "applicant_id", referencedColumnName = "id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "skill_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
    private List<SkillEntity> skills = new ArrayList<SkillEntity>();

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "ATS_APPLICANT_LOCATION", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "applicant_id", referencedColumnName = "id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "location_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
    private List<LocationEntity> locations = new ArrayList<LocationEntity>();
```

SkillEntity :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ATS_SKILL")
public class SkillEntity implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 42)
    @Column(name = "name", length = 42, nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String name;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "ATS_SKILL_CATEGORY", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "skill_id", referencedColumnName = "id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "category_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
    private List<CategoryEntity> categories = new ArrayList<CategoryEntity>();
```

CategoryEntity :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ATS_CATEGORY")
public class CategoryEntity implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 42)
    @Column(name = "name", length = 42, nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String name;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "ATS_CATEGORY_DOMAIN", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "category_id", referencedColumnName = "id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "domain_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
    private List<DomainEntity> domains = new ArrayList<DomainEntity>();
```

EDIT 2 :
DomainEntity :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ATS_DOMAIN")
public class DomainEntity implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 42)
    @Column(name = "name", length = 42, nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String name;
```

Comment: you should fill in the null columns {category_id,domain_id} because it has not null contraints.

Comment: yes i know this my problem but it should be automatic when i add one skill to an applicant the table can find the applicant's id and the skill's id but not category's id which already exist.

Comment: you should add some code relevant to your problem so we can help.

Comment: @LKTN.25 just added the entites look the edit.

Comment: Try to remove the `referencedColumnName = "id"` from the mapping annotation. Also please add DomainEntity

Comment: ATS_APPLICANT_SKILL table is pretty messed up mapping table. it should only have the skillid and applicantid. what is the use of categoryid and domainid there if you have another mapping table for them. your database structure is very complex.

Comment: @StanislavL how the program will find the id if i do not specify it ?. See EDIT 2 for domain Entity.

Comment: @LKTN.25 yes i know it is auto genrated by the Annotations maybe you know how to remove column Category_id and domain_id from table ATS_APPLICANT_SKILL ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I succeed by using @ElementCollection annotation on skills.